# programming for keyword search from database?

Tags: c#, sql

Hello I have a table with following columns.

```
Profile_ID,
Name,
Age,
More_Info_about family,
qualification details, 
job details and 
partner_preference
```

I have to search on keyword basis and keyword is to be taken from textbox.

The search result should be in such a way so that if keyword presents in starting, ending and in between the sentence of any of the columns presents in where conditions.

I tried LIKE '" + txtbox_keyword.Text + "'
but is not working properly it is not searching data if keyowrd is present in between sentense.

```sql
select (Profile_ID,Name,Age, More_info_about_family,Job_Business_Location_City,Salary 
from tblRegistration  
WHERE More_info_about_family LIKE '" + txtbox_keyword.Text + "' 
   OR LIKE '" + txtbox_keyword.Text + "' 
   OR origin LIKE '" + txtbox_keyword.Text + "' 
   OR Job_Detail LIKE '" + txtbox_keyword.Text + "' ", con);
```

Comment: Use % in the argument of LIKE. e.g. LIKE 'SomethingAtTheBeginning%'

Comment: Gah, the sql injection vulnerability, it burns us!

Comment: you should create a store procedure for this case

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow.
Please be very careful about allowing a textbox input be injected directly into your sql query. It leaves your database very vulnerable and makes it possible for the user to do really bad things to your database or even your server.
Please read up on SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

Use sqlParameter for except sql injection and you need add %% in your query to search by field.

```
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@keyWord",txtbox_keyword.Text);

select (Profile_ID,Name,Age, More_info_about_family,Job_Business_Location_City,Salary 
from tblRegistration  
WHERE More_info_about_family LIKE '%@keyWord%' 
   OR LIKE '%@keyWord%' 
   OR origin LIKE '%@keyWord%' 
   OR Job_Detail LIKE '%@keyWord%', con,parameter);
```